# Error retrieving MailChimp datacenter string

Tags: guzzle, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a problem solving this issue. 
Following the steps in the documentation here https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/), I made through 6 out of 7 steps. The last being making a request to metadata uri endpoint.

**The instructions in the docs are as follows:**
 1. To start your application’s connection to MailChimp, start by sending the user to the authorize_uri.
 2. The user will input their username and password to approve your application. “Remember Me” cookies aren’t permitted here.
 3. After the user authorizes your application, our server will redirect your user back to the redirect_uri, along with a code you can exchange for an access_token. The code is valid for 30 seconds.
 4. Your application should then make an out-of-band request to the access_token_uri using the code our server provided.
 5. Our server returns an access_token, which completes the official OAuth2 flow.
 6. To complete the MailChimp flow, make another RESTful request using an OAuth2 client to the metadata_uri.
 7. Our server will return a datacenter string, API endpoint, and login URL, as described in the following list.

This is what my request looks like:

```
`$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/']);
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'metadata', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => "OAuth $access_token"
                ]
            ]);`
```

The access token is replaced but the error message from the request is this.

`'{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Unable to load login and user"}`

Comment: Hi @Paul, Did you solve this?